# Toggle divs inside a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to write short piece of code where I have a bunch of divs inside one big and I want a class called "focused" to first be put to the first div, then after 5 seconds toggle to next one, and so on. I'd also want this to be loopable.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="rowwrapper">
  <div class="flipcontainer">
    <div class="card focused">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flipcontainer">
    <div class="card">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flipcontainer">
    <div class="card">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  etc…

</div>
```

I started with a JS code by myself, but it doesn't seem to cooperate with me.

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".rowwrapper").next(".card").toggleClass("focused");
  }, 5000)
});
```

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to cooperate with me" does not tell us what it IS doing. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you're trying to do. Try this:

## Example

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        //  get currently focused card, also remove focused class
        var current = $('.rowwrapper .focused').removeClass('focused'),
            //  attempt to get next card in line by going to current card's parent
            //    then going to the next card parent and grab its inner card
            next = current.closest('.flipcontainer').next('.flipcontainer:first').find('.card');
        //  this simply checks if next is set, if not, let's grab the first one again
        if (!next.length) next = $('.rowwrapper .flipcontainer:first .card');
        //  add focused class to new card
        next.addClass('focused');
    }, 1000);
})
```

#### Random Fun with This

Answer (score 2):

```
$.fn.circularFocus = function(interval, focusClass) {
    if (typeof interval === 'undefined')   interval = 1000;
    if (typeof focusClass === 'undefined') focusClass = 'focused';

    var cards = this.toArray();
    var idCurrentFocusedCard = 0;

    window.setInterval(function () {
        $(cards[idCurrentFocusedCard]).removeClass(focusClass);
        idCurrentFocusedCard = idCurrentFocusedCard === cards.length ? 0 : idCurrentFocusedCard + 1;
        $(cards[idCurrentFocusedCard]).addClass(focusClass);
    }, interval);

    return this;
};

$('.card').circularFocus(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accesssing the correct DIV containers. $(".rowwrapper").next('.card') will atempt to locate the next sibling DIV of "rowwrapper".  Are you removing the class from the previous container?

```
$(function() {
  var i = setInterval(function() {
     $(".rowwrapper").children().next(".card").addClass("focused");
  }, 5000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this ([**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nUd8U/1/))

```
$(function(){
    var divs = $('div.rowwrapper').children(), i = 0;
    $(divs[i]).find('.card').addClass('focused');
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.card').removeClass('focused');
        i = i+1 <= divs.length-1 ? i+1 : 0;
        $(divs[i]).find('.card').addClass('focused');
    }, 5000);
});
```